# Performing an OpenSCAP Remediation via a chroot session -- "Can't perform remediation in offline mode" Error

Tags: linux, security, redhat, chroot, openscap

I am attempting to perform an OpenSCAP remediation through a chroot session. My command is structured as follows:

```sh
  oscap-chroot /mnt/chroot_fs \
        xccdf eval \
        --remediate \
        --results results.xml \
        --report report.html \
        --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui \
        ssg-rhel7-ds-1.2.xml
```

When the command executes, it performs a scan successfully indicating a handful of `pass` and `fail` results. Then, when it moves on to the remediation phase, it says:

```sh
 --- Starting Remediation ---
OpenSCAP Error: Can't perform remediation in offline mode: not implemented [/builddir/build/BUILD/openscap-1.3.3/src/XCCDF/xccdf_session.c:1690]
```

Is remediation through a chroot session not possible at this time? If not, how can you perform a remediation against a *remote* target?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Openscap cannot perform remote remediations. `oscap-chroot` and `oscap-ssh` are meant for scans only. The recommended solution, from what I can tell, is to use `oscap xccdf generate fix` using the `results.xml` file generated by oscap-chroot. Then run this remediation script manually against the remote host.